# No table in memory after logout in kdb

Tags: kdb

When I logout from session my tables are deleted.

What should I do, so when I connect to kdb I see again my tables.

My tables should contain several month data, which added from files incrementally. Also other people should have access to them.

PS: of course, I understand, I could save them to file and then restore. But I need them in memory without saving to any files

Simple example

I load/create table

```
rlwrap $HOME/l64/l64/q
t:flip `c1`c2`c3!(`a`b`c;42;1.1)
```

Ctrl+z - logout

```
rlwrap $HOME/l64/l64/q
```

no table `t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `rlwrap $HOME/l64/l64/q` again opens a *new* `q` session. You should not expect to see a table from another session in there.

If you want to pull data from one `q` session to another you will need to use [ipc](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/11_IO/#116-interprocess-communication). To do this you will need to open a port in your first `q` session either with a command line flag:

```
rlwrap $HOME/l64/l64/q -p 5042
```

or from within the process itself:

```
q)\p 5042
q)t:flip `c1`c2`c3!(`a`b`c;42;1.1)
```

Then in a second `q` process can pull the table over:

```
q)h:hopen`::5042
q)h`t
c1 c2 c3
---------
a  42 1.1
b  42 1.1
c  42 1.1
q)hclose h
```

Anyone else on the same server will be able to connect to your port. If your tables are large enough (especially if they're partitioned) you'll want to be careful with what kind of queries that any other user can use. I recommend reading through the Kx white paper on [Permissions with kdb+](https://code.kx.com/q/wp/permissions/).

Answer (score 3):

The second time you run q you are starting a new q session.
If you want to re connect to the existing session bring it back to the foreground with `fg`

For other users to have access to these tables you will have to run q on a port and allow users to access and make queries via hopen

Answer (score 2):

If these are tables you are defining such as `` t:flip `c1`c2`c3!(`a`b`c;42;1.1) ``

You could create a example.q file which defines them. Then start q like so:

`rlwrap $HOME/l64/l64/q example.q`

Also I would recommend adding q as an alias with rlwrap to .bashrc so that you don't have to type that every time.

`alias q='QHOME=~/q rlwrap -r ~/q/l32/q'`

https://code.kx.com/q/learn/install/linux/

Comment: this simple `t` is an example. My tables should contain several month data, which added from files incrementally. Also other people should have access to them

Comment: There is no other way around this but to persist the data to disk. Anything stored in RAM is lost on logging out. See here from Q for Mortals on saving tables to disk. 
https://code.kx.com/q4m3/11_IO/

Comment: Since you are talking about several months of data, a date partitioned hdb may be more what you want. Also be aware you need to enumerate sym columns with .Q.en before saving to disk https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb+/#1431-partitions

Comment: Also with regards to other people accessing the data. You could setup your q process as a server and other users could use hopen on their own  q process to connect to it over IPC and grab what data they need. https://code.kx.com/q4m3/11_IO/#1142-using-hopen-and-hclose